# Marvel vs DC: Equivalent Characters

Tags: marvel, dc

I'm searching for a list of Marvel and DC equivalent characters. By "equivalent" I understand that one character is a copy of another (it looks, behave similar or has similar super powers). Many examples presented [in this talk (PL)](https://youtu.be/7XrL2GN0_-8) started similar to orginal characters but evolves to completely different heroes (e.g., [Moonight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Werewolf_by_Night) and [Batman](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detective_Comics)).

**EDIT**: I'm looking for **main** characters only. By main chararcet I understand one with its own comics. For example Gladiator is a part of X-Men series but hasn't have dedicated series for him (unlike Wolverine) so should not be included in comparison although he is similar to Superman (alien, last of it's species, super strength) On the other hand Quicksilver and Flash both have their own comics therefore can be compared.

Comment: This seems very broad.

Comment: I think subjectivity is an equally big problem. Just from the list posted so far, I was surprised by the choice for Marvel equivalent of Superman because I've heard Sentry referred to that way a few times in the past.

Comment: I voted to reopen because I think @janisz's answer demonstrates sufficiently that it's a good question. It could only possibly be 'broad' if there is a significant amount of correlation / duplication between brands, which in of itself is an interesting topic / question. If, on the other hand, there are few or no examples, then it is not too broad

Comment: There are [756](http://marvel.com/universe/Category:Heroes) marvel heroes and probably more characters that appear in comics.  I updated the questions to narrow comparison by including only main characters.

Answer (score 7):

From [this talk (PL)](https://youtu.be/7XrL2GN0_-8)

1. Werewolf by night vs Detective commics - starts different but after some time both character use their money to fight bad guy. Both of them fight by night.
2. X-Men vs Doom Patrol - teams of outcast that fight evil

   > Some similarities exist between the original Doom Patrol and Marvel Comics' original X-Men.[6] Both include misfit superheroes shunned by society and both are led by men of preternatural intelligence who use wheelchairs. These similarities ultimately led series writer Arnold Drake to argue that the concept of the X-Men must have been based on the Doom Patrol.[Wiki](https://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Detective_Comics)
3. Man Thing vs Swamp Thing - history about guy whi went to swamp and changed.
4. Magneto vs Dr Polaris - similar appearance and power
5. Dr. Strange vs Dr. Fate
6. Fantastic Four vs Excalibur - family go into space and is radiated.
7. [Gladiator](http://marvel.com/universe/Gladiator_(Kallark)) vs Superman
8. Nova vs Green Lantern - similar origin
9. Winter Soldier vs Red Hood
10. Legion of Superheroes vs Imperial Guard
11. The Lizard vs Man-Bat
12. Big Barda vs Gamora
13. Justice League vs Squadron Supreme

[image: Marvel vs DC]